# Android: Extra bytes in file transferred to device

Tags: android, file-io

So, I have a simple Android app that connects to a Java Server application using Sockets.
Specifically, I want to be able to send a file from the Server application to the Android app and then store that file in internal memory on the device. 
The basis of the server code for transferring the file is:

```
BufferedInputStream  bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(new File(System.getProperty("user.home"), "text.txt")));
BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
byte buffer[] = new byte[1024];
int read;
while ((read = bis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    bos.write(buffer, 0, read);
}
bos.flush();
bos.close();
```

and the Client code to receive the file is as follows:

```
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(openFileOutput("text.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
byte buffer[] = new byte[1024];
int read;
while ((read = bis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    bos.write(buffer, 0, read);
}
bos.flush();
bos.close();
```

The code appears to work fine when the client code is in a standard Java application, that is, the file sends successfully from server to client.
The problem arises when I use this code in an Android app. (Note: I use a standard FileOutputStream in the standard Java app instead of the

```
    openFileOutput("text.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE))
```

line above).

For example purposes, the file I am transferring is a simple UTF-8 text file, which contains a single string

```
    This is a text file.
```

However, when I pull this file I have copied to the emulator, from the "/data/data//files" folder on the emulator, there are an extra couple of bytes at the top of the file so the content is now

```
    ¨ÌThis is a text file.
```

I have no idea why this is happening and it has me stumped. I think the problem might be related to the line:

```
    BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(openFileOutput("text.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
```

but I can't quite figure it out.

Any suggestions as to what I am doing wrong would be most helpful.

Thank you in advance

Comment: What kind of sockets do you use? Maybe the extra bytes are the tail of an extended transport layer header that the android tcp/udp stack do not expect.

Comment: Those are the *literal* characters? Specifically, the characters you are seeing are not the UTF8 BOM?

Comment: Also your code snippets could be in some context where the sockets in- or output stream is not freshly opened but maybe where used before, eg reading some headers or other tokens, and where not emptied by that read.

Comment: Thank you all for your help, it is very much appreciated. Your comments got me thinking and I think I may have a workaround for the moment. I simply sent an empty object prior to sending the file and then just discarding it, with that the problem disappears. Thanks again.

Comment: @androider have you got the solution of that problem?